# What is the time complexity if we apply merge sort on an array containing all the elements same?

Tags: mergesort

Given array is 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
If we apply merge sort on this array,what will be the time complexity in big oh notation?

Comment: The number of compares will be cut in half, but a standard merge sort will always do the same number of moves, so time complexity remains at O(n log(n)). A hybrid insertion sort / natural merge sort would detect an already sorted array with time complexity O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of generic merge sort does not depend on the contents of the array. It performs **N.log(N)** comparisons and moves. Some optimized versions might detect special cases and execute in linear time **O(N)**.